# Symfony 2.2 extend ExceptionController

Tags: php, symfony, exception, symfony-2.2

This question is related to the [following change](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/35d63df044cba20cdf441963ca85a7f4d51200cc) (part of Symfony 2.2 release):

**Part 1**

In pre-2.2 Symfony, I was overriding `ExceptionController` to display some custom error pages.

I did that via:

```
parameters:
       twig.exception_listener.controller: My\CustomBundle\CustomExceptionController::showAction
```

Now, after upgrading to 2.2, I can no longer do that, because an exception is thrown while generating an exception (no pun intended):

> ExceptionController::__construct() must be an instance of Twig_Environment, none given, called in...

Since `ExceptionController` is a service now, how can I override that, and what do I need to change in my old code?

All I did in the custom class, is changed the template reference in showAction method:

```
$template = new TemplateReference('TwigBundle', 'Exception', $name, $format, 'twig');
```

**Part 2**

Since `ExceptionController` no longer extends `ContainerAware`, how do I get to the current container? Is it enough to implement `ContainerAwareInterface`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should change a couple of this:

1. you need to **inherit the `ExceptionController`** in your custom Exception controller.
2. you need to **override the `twig.controller.exception.class` parameter**. As you can see in [the service file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/35d63df044cba20cdf441963ca85a7f4d51200cc#L3R116), it uses the `twig.controller.exception.class` parameter to identify the exception controller class. Now override it with your class:

   ```
   parameters:
       twig.controller.exception.class: My\CustomBundle\CustomExceptionController
   ```
3. you need to edit the signature of the `showAction` to follow the [new signature](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/35d63df044cba20cdf441963ca85a7f4d51200cc#L1R48)

   > Since `ExceptionController` no longer extends `ContainerAware`, how do I get to the current container? Is it enough to implement `ContainerAwareInterface`?

No, services shouldn't *never* inject the container. You should inject the services you need in the constructor, as is done with the `Twig_Environment` service.

Inside your Exception controller, you get access to the `$this->twig` property for the twig service. And the new signature gets a `$request` parameter, to get the request. I don't think you need more. (you also get `$this->debug`)

Comment: Thanks Wouter! What I was missing is the twig.controller.exception.class override. Works like a charm now.

Comment: Actually for the 2nd part of my question, in the previous implementation of ExceptionController, I was able to retrieve parameter from $this->container->getParameter(). How can I retrieve that same parameter in the new custom exception controller, now that it's a service? Is using $this->twig->getGlobals() would be the right way to go?

Comment: I found this tutorial useful too: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep3/error-pages

Comment: I'm getting the same error, I'm following [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller) using Symfony 3.2.0-DEV and I'm already inheriting from ExceptionController.. How can I solve?